# Make modal open after request - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i have a register modal with vuejs and i need if user inserted the wrong information in the form and the information didn't validated in controller (using laravel) i could redirect user to the same page with modal open (i have "showRegister" in data and i need to make it open with "showRegister : true" after redirect)

```
    new Vue({
        el: '.LR-PC',
        data: {
            showRegister: false,
            showLogin:false,
        }
    });
```

on default when we redirect to page `showRegister` is `false`

code:

```
                <script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
                    <transition name="modal">
                        <div class="modal-mask">
                            <div class="modal-wrapper">
                                <div class="modal-container">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <i class="fa fa-window-close" @click="$emit('close')" style="margin : 0 0 0 100%;"></i>
                                        <slot name="header">
                                            create user
                                        </slot>
                                    </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <slot name="body">
                                            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                                                @csrf
                                            <input class="input-style-1"  type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="9"/>
                                            <input  class="input-style-1"  type="text" name="f-name" id="f-name" maxlength="10"/>
                                            <input class="input-style-1" type="email" name="email" maxlength="50">
                                            <input name="password" class="input-style-1" type="password" maxlength="18">
                                            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="input-style-1" maxlength="18" onchange="hi(sa)">
                                            <div class="r-phone-number input-style-1">
                                            <input type="tel" name="phone"  style="margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; width: 323px; text-align: right; position: relative; right: auto; left: 15px;" class="input-style-1">
                                            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                                            </div>
                                                @if($errors->any())
                                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                        <ul>
                                                            @foreach($errors as $error)
                                                                {{$error}}
                                                            @endforeach
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                @endif
                                                <slot name="footer">
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block wid-100">register</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </slot>
                                            </form>
                                                </slot>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </transition>
                </script>
                <a id="show-modal" @click="showRegister = true" class="l-main">register</a>
                <modal v-if="showRegister" @close="showRegister = false">
                </modal>
```

Comment: This register modal is a custom component, or it comes from a module? Can you post the sample code for a modal?

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect back, pass an extra paramenter in view like: `view('yourRoute', ['registerError'=>true])`.
In your vue component receive it like `<lr-pc register-error="{{$registerError}}"></lr-pc>`. So you could handle it inside vue element.

```
new Vue({
        el: '.LR-PC',
        props:{
           registerError:{
               type:Boolean,
               default: false
           }
        },
        data: {
            showRegister: this.registerError,
            showLogin:false,
        }
    });
```

Of course, if you wish an inverse logic, use `!this.registerError`.